# CorePlot: How can I scroll to the end of the line of a scatter plot graph?

Tags: ios, iphone, core-plot

I have a core plot graph which extends over the visible screen area. User interaction is enabled, and when the use opens the view controller, the beginning of the chart is displayed, but I would like to display the end, and the user then may scroll vertically to the left if he wants to see older data (Note: the x-Axis is chronological)

Is there a way to scroll an area into view, same like scrolling into view in a uiscrollview?

Comment: Did you look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14123949/enable-x-axis-horizontal-scroll-in-coreplot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let consider your total area is 300 and you're going to display the initial content from 250-300.

Then, set the `xRange` as **250-300** and set the `globalXRange` as **0-300**.

For more: [Core Plot (iOS) - CPTXYPlotSpace](http://core-plot.googlecode.com/hg-history/efa73ee50d8edfd0e1d4294cf4bd2c07d9f8af77/documentation/html/iOS/interface_c_p_t_x_y_plot_space.html#)